# How to get array index from Oracle JSON column?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

Having a JSON like this (I know that JSON doesn't support comments. Used in this case to illustrate the idea):

```
{
    "people": [
        {                       --//  <-- index 0
            "id": 100,
            "name": "John Doe"
        },
        {                       --//  <-- index 1
            "id": 101,
            "name": "Jane Roe"
        }
    ]
}
```

We can select values from specific elements in the array doing something like this:

```
SELECT name
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    '{
        "people": [
            {
                "id": 100,
                "name": "John Doe"
            },
            {
                "id": 101,
                "name": "Jane Roe"
            },
        ]
    }', '$.people[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
        ID      NUMBER      PATH '$.id',
        NAME    VARCHAR2    PATH '$.name'
    )
) info
WHERE info.id = 101
```

Result:

```
NAME
--------
Jane Roe
```

Is there a way to get the element index in the array? Something like:

```
SELECT array_index    --//  <-- how get the array index of the element found?
FROM JSON_TABLE(
--// ...
) info
WHERE info.id = 101
```

Result:

```
ARRAY_INDEX
-----------
1
```

Is possible to do something like this using JSON support in Oracle 12c?

Comment: A JSON is parsed into relation records. Relation records do not have array index. You may assign numbers to the selected records using rownum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
COLUMNS(
        idx FOR ORDINALITY,
        ID      NUMBER      PATH '$.id',
        NAME    VARCHAR2    PATH '$.name'
)
```

should work for you

Comment: This adds a rownum to the resultlist, but OP wants the index of the original list, which would be 1 for id 101 and 0 for id 100

Comment: The answer is correct, `(idx-1)` always gives desired index.
BTW, be careful with `for ordinality` in 12.1.0.2.0. There is a bug that requires a patch https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=patch&id=20885778 
In 12.2 it works fine

Answer (score 1):

As ArtBajji wrote, the rows itself dont have a index. Therefor you need to create a "fake id" that is relatively fixed.

This can be achieved by giving your data a order(`order by id`) and a index (`rownum`). Then select from this "modified" table

```
SELECT name, indx FROM (
SELECT ind.*, rownum "INDX"
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    '{
        "people": [
            {
                "id": 100,
                "name": "John Doe"
            },
            {
                "id": 101,
                "name": "Jane Roe"
            },
        ]
    }', '$.people[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
        ID      NUMBER      PATH '$.id',
        NAME    VARCHAR2    PATH '$.name'
    )
) ind order by id) tab
WHERE tab.id = 101
```

Yields 1 for id 100 and 2 for id 101.

Be aware that the index of the elements 100 and 101 grow by one if you insert a item with a id < 100.